# Graph Laplacian defined as sum

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

The Laplacian of a weighted can be defined both as $D-W$ where D is the diagonal matrix with entries the degrees of each node and $W = (w)_{ij}$ is the matrix of weights. I don't see how it can also be equal to

$$\sum_{i \lt j} w_{ij}(e_i-e_j)(e_i-e_j)^T$$

What in this definition accounts for the diagonal elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula holds if you assume that the graph is symmetric.
The reason the diagonal elements $w_{ii}$ don't appear in the second formula is that they cancel out in the first formula $L=D-W$ as well. Remember that $D$'s $i$-th diagonal element $d_{ii}$ is the sum of the the elements on the $i$-th row (or column) of $W$. That sum contains $w_{ii}$, so when you subtract $W$, it gets canceled out.

**Formal proof:**
Start by noting that

Because $$(e_i-e_j)(e_i-e_j)^T = (e_j-e_i)(e_j-e_i)^T $$ and that if $i=j$, then the above is also equal to $0$.

With that, and using $w_{ij}=w_{ji}$,
$$\sum_{i \lt j} w_{ij}(e_i-e_j)(e_i-e_j)^T = \frac 1 2 \sum_{i, j} w_{ij}(e_i-e_j)(e_i-e_j)^T$$

Note that $E_{ij}=e_ie_j^T$ is the $n\times n$ matrix with zeros everywhere, except with a $1$ at the $(i, j)$ position. Then
$$\begin{split} \sum_{i, j} w_{ij}(e_i-e_j)(e_i-e_j)^T &= \sum_{i,j} w_{ij}(E_{ii} + E_{jj} -E_{ij}-E_{ji})\\
&= \sum_{i}E_{ii} \left ( \sum_j w_{ij} \right) + \sum_{j}E_{jj} \left ( \sum_i w_{ij} \right) - 2 \sum_{i,j} w_{ij}E_{ij}\\
&= 2\sum_{i}d_{ii}E_{ii}- 2 \sum_{i,j} w_{ij}E_{ij}\\
&= 2(D - W)
\end{split}$$